# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{np}}=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

By [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests) we can conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{np}}$ is convergent for $0<p\leq 1.$

question: Can we compute the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{np}}$?

Comment: It's an [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$x=\frac 1{2^p}\qquad \implies \qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{np}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\,x^n=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\,x^{n-1}$$ Integrate the last term  with repect to $x$ which makes a very simple geometric series. Differentiate the result, muliply by $x$ and replace $x$ by its definition.